# Can't get Facebook album photos anymore using $facebook->api('ALBUM_ID/photos?limit=0')

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have been using Facebook graph Api, for a long time, in my website to allow users to grab their photos and use in mine.

A few days ago, I noticed that the following code:

```
$facebook->api('ALBUM_ID/photos?limit=0')
```

is no longer retrieving the photos of the given album.

Has facebook changed it's API?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the [roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/):

> ```
> FQL and Graph API limit=0 change
> ```
>
> Currently, we have a bug where limit=0 returns all results. After the migration period, specifying a limit of 0 in FQL or the Graph API
>   will return zero results.